# NPM install installs dependencies that are not in my package.json

Tags: npm

I just added a depedency to my project and did an **npm install**. However, I get 20 modules in my node_modules folder. Why is this happening? I only need one module.

Comment: Probably your dependency's dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`npm install\` add other modules that I didn't ask for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191960/why-does-npm-install-add-other-modules-that-i-didnt-ask-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In NPM 3, the dependency hierarchy is flat by default](http://www.felixrieseberg.com/npm-v3-is-out-and-its-a-really-big-deal-for-windows/), so you are probably seeing your dependency's dependencies.